# The vim command line launched by git mergetool

Tags: git, vim

What is the final command launched by git mergetool when the following is set in the config:

```
git config --global merge.tool vimdiff
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
vim -d $MERGED $LOCAL $BASE $REMOTE -c wincmd J
```

where arguments are different stages of a merge. See description at https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-mergetool#git-mergetool--tlttoolgt

See also https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3985/git-mergetool-vimdiff-command

Comment: Hey phd, the vim layout invoked in the newer git versions is with the merged buffers horizontally split below. The above cmd doesn't seem to give that!

Comment: Brilliant!
Thanks